# twitter-like PUSH / data stream server side implementation?

Tags: python, django, websocket

I'm trying to implement a live data stream feature (similar to Twitter's stream API) into a `django 1.9` web app that I've made.

After looking at the streaming portions of [Python-Twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) library in Python, in `twitter/api.py`, I had a couple of questions about how the server-side of this implementation works.

It seems that the stream request is a just a normal GET/POST request to a normal URL. However, this URL sends asynchronous data back to the client. It doesn't appear that there is any kind of persistent connection between this API and the twitter stream servers. Ie, no tcp socket, no `WebSocket`, nothing like that. I've tried using `StreamingHttpResponse` but that seems to just build a queue of data to be flushed all at once to the client instead of piece-wise.

I've gotten this to work over typical tcp sockets, but this needs to work in a very similar fashion to the `Python-Twitter` library.

If someone were to try to recreate something like this (in Python), how would they? This seems like black magic to me at this point.

Is there a way to just send HTTP data back to a client over and over again without requiring a new request each time (or blocking the rest of the django app)?

For example, something like this:

```
def stream(request):
    while True:
        if newServerAction:
            HttpResponse(newServerAction, content_type='application_json').send(request)
        else:
            sleep(1)
```

Or is there some other approach altogether that I'm simply missing?

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Look at getstream.io. Very convenient and powerful cross-language library with their own website and distributed services that does exactly that